# The physics of hit & run

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, acceleration, time

It is usually said that you can minimize the damage caused by a car crash by increasing its duration. This way the impulse (F x dt) will be the same, but the F component wil decrease and hence the acceleration for the passengers. For example, by manufacturing the cars of steel that is deformable, you make them stick to each other and thus travel together during more time, instead of bouncing off and accelerating sharply. Logically, the opposite is also true: by chosing an elastic naterial, you would reduce collision time and increase the damage. But I wonder if you can obtain this result without changing the actors, without altering the display, just by reducing the interaction time.

For example, the bird pecks at the wood of the tree. Of course, thus the surface exposed to the force is reduced and this maximizes the presure and the impact of the force. But the bird also uses quick repeated movements for some reason, doesn't it?

I tend to think that the same rationale lies behind in both cases.

When the interaction time increases with a deformable car, it is because this material is like a coward army with little cohesion. If the soldiers (molecules) are hit and  displaced, there is no courage (restoring force) making them strike back, so they are disbanded (potential energy is not re-converted into kinetic energy). Hence the  non-bouncing off and the longer interaction time.

When the interaction time decreases out of the sheer will of the bird, the effect is that its beak, even if it faces a brave army, just hits a couple of soldiers and retreats before they can obtain assistance from their colleagues... This would be a sort of hit & run strategy, guerrillas war... reducing the attack time and maximizing the force?

Well, that is what I initially thought but have doubts...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. You seem to be just expressing your ideas and looking for approval.

Comment: Woodpeckers have extremely specialised mechanisms which allow them to peck the way they do without getting brain damage.  Humans ... don't.

Comment: VTC as per sammy gerbil, no actual physics question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by manufacturing the cars of steel that is deformable, you make them stick to each other

It is not so much a "sticking together" effect, but rather a "pillow" effect. Even if they don't stick at all, the deformation still absorbs energy. This reduces the total kinetic energy.

> Logically, the opposite is also true: by chosing an elastic naterial, you would reduce collision time and increase the damage.

"Elasticity" is not the opposite of "deformable". You can easily have a non elastic surface that doesn't deform. A stone for example. Those two are not opposites but rather in the same category: first a material *elastically compresses/stretches* and **then** it *permanently deforms*. Not either one or the other. These are called elastic deformation and plastic deformation, respectively.

Both the amounts of plastic deformation *and* of elastic deformation are *positive* factors increasing the duration of impact. Think of a deformable car and think of a trampoline; both reduce impact time and save your from injury.

> When the interaction time increases with a deformable car, it is because this material is like a coward army with little cohesion. If the soldiers (molecules) are hit and displaced, there is no courage (restoring force) making them strike back, so they are disbanded (potential energy is not re-converted into kinetic energy). Hence the non-bouncing off and the shorter interaction time.

(I believe you mean "longer interaction time" in that last sentence here.) This analogy is fine so far, as far as I can see.

> When the interaction time decreases out of sheer will of the bird, the effect is that its beak, even if it faces a brave army, just hits a couple of soldiers and retreats before they can obtain assistance from their colleagues.

This analogy is a little bit odd. I'm pretty sure (without being bird expert) that the quick head withdrawal happens because if simply bounces back. The backwards motion is not "out of sheer will" but simply the bounce. Then the impact is not independent of the motion afterwards, because the momentum change is larger which is a force applied in the wood. I do not believe the "retreating fast to reduce impact time" analogy is working here and I do not see the correlation with car collisions.

Comment: Steeven@. As to last paragraph, I understand and agree

Comment: Steeven@. FIRST PARAGRAPH: ok, I agree that no literal “sticking together” is necessary, what is key is deformation, although you may agree with me that deformation means less transfer of KE and hence more or less  motion in unison of the two bodies after the crash.

Comment: PARAGRAPHS 2 and & 3: there are 2 understandings of "elasticity”. Mine: after the collision, there's zero permanent deformation =  there will have been, at microscopic level, compressing/stretching but restoring forces have re-stablished equilibrium  = all PE has re-converted into KE. That is the meaning  when we refer to a fully “elastic” or the ”elasticity” modulus of a material (although actually“rigidity” looks like a better word). The other is yours = “temporary and macroscopic” deformation, isn’t it? I missed this concept, a useful one = a property that enlarges interaction time.

Comment: PARAGRAPH 4: you are right, I will edit. PARAGRAPH 5: I realize that you are right, the beak bounces back. Still there may be some sort of "giving" in the bird behavior, like when you smash a nail into the wall and quickly release the grip over the hammer, thus reducing tension. Like when a boxer relaxes the neck upon receiving a punch. So the bird behavior might be an example of right the opposite of what I was saying, an example of increasing instead of reducing collision time, so as to reduce the damage. Do you agree?

Comment: @Sierra Yes, by "elasticity" I mean what the elastic modulus refers to. But there's no difference from the microscopic to the macroscopic view on this - for both cases, the elastic effect (compressing and returning back to original size) **increases** the impact duration. Think of when the object hits and when it leaves again: the more elastic (microscopically or macroscopically), the more contact time, because the compression and returning to original size takes longer time. The reason a trampoline is working *is* because it at the molecular scale is more elastic than, say, granite.

Comment: @ Steeven ok to all, my only disagreement is that you are equating "elasticity" with easiness of deformation, whilst technically elasticity means the opposite, "resistance to elastic deformation". This resistance is measured, for a material, by its elasticity modulus, Young's modulus in longitudinal deformation. Hence granite's is very high, because it resists well, while rubber's is low. In fact for a specific structure, the property is "stiffness". What you refer to is instead the "flexibility" of an object. Thus granite is + elastic, the trampoline + flexible.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, following that approach, the correct sentence would be: the material granite is more elastic, a granite rock is stiffer; the material wood is less elastic, a wood trampoline is more flexible. Maybe this is a subject for another question...

Comment: Wait... I have just read that, before awarding the title "elastic" to a material, one must also consider its elasticity limit. So granite has high modulus but short limit, while rubber has low modulus but higher limit, so it stretches more and... is therefore a more "elastic" material...? Not easy terminology, in any case!

Comment: @Sierra Ahmm... A stone is not elastic. A **very elastic** material can experience big deformation while still returning to original size. Granite can't do that. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(physics))

Comment: Well, that is what I was conceding in my last comment. The two precise definitions are (a) elasticity modulus and (b) limit of elasticity. Granite has a high modulus (a) but a short elasticity limit (b). When measuring its "elasticity" relative to another material... we should focus rather on (b) how far it stretches/compresses while still being able to return to equilibrium instead of (a) the force with which it returns. Fine for me! I would just point out that the relative weight of each factor (a versus b) is not clear. I will pose another question about it!